# App process network, setProcessDefaultNetwork / bindProcessToNetwork Android API in Android L

Tags: java, android, networking

If app process network [setProcessDefaultNetwork](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network)) set  at java level, if any request at low level(C/navtive) will go over the the Network set?

Thanks

Nitz

Answer (score 1):

As per my testing if setProcessDefaultNetwork(dataNetwork) set at java Platform level,the C and java level transport request will always go on dataNetwork.Even when wifi is on.

The app process needs to same.

"[process-wide via setProcessDefaultNetwork(Network)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html)"

**Edit 19-10-2015 :**[setProcessDefaultNetwork is now deprecated and  bindProcessToNetwork to be used](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#setProcessDefaultNetwork(android.net.Network))